# Can linux kernel module be removed before module init has completed?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Lets say my kernel module have the init and exit function bellow:

```c
module_init(init_module);
module_exit(cleanup_module);
```

Can the kernel module be removed, thus calling `cleanup_module()`, before the module init has completed/while `init_module()` is being executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In module.c `do_init_module` does a `module_put` AFTER calling `init_module`, so I assume somewhere it has a reference to the module. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9-rc7/source/kernel/module.c#L3658

`delete_module` checks the refcount in `try_stop_module` BEFORE calling `free_module`.  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9-rc7/source/kernel/module.c#L1025  `module_mutex` prevents simultaneous changes to the structures involved.

It looks like root can certainly call rmmod while init is running.  If it happens before the put, it will fail.  If it happens after the put, it will succeed.  Either way, no incorrect operation will occur in the kernel (unless force operation is used, as Vijay points out).

Comment: Is this a "yes", a "no" or an "I don't know"?

Comment: It means yes and no.  Editted

Comment: @stark So it's safe to say that there's no need for `cleanup_module()` to verify if the memory allocated in `init_module()` has been allocated before freeing it? If the allocation failed in `init_module()`, `init_module()` will return with an error code and `cleanup_module()` will not be called. `cleanup_module()` can only be called if `init_module()` has returned without an error code thus meaning all memory has been allocated. Is that correct? (unless force operation is used)

Comment: Assuming that the module init routine is written properly, yes.

Comment: @stark Of course, `init_module()` need to implement it's own cleanup mechanism in case of a failed allocation before returning with an error code.

Answer (score 0):

i believe that if the option `CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD` was set when you built your kernel then it is possible to forcefully remove the module using `rmmod -f`  or `modprobe`

Answer (score 0):

If the module init handler returns an error, the module exit handler won't be called. This implies that the module init handler has to return before the module exit handler can be called.